# C# using reflection to access Window properties

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

How do you use reflection to access properties of `Window` objects?

Here's a minimal example:

`.xaml` file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <TextBox x:Name="Textbox" Text=""/>
</Window>
```

code behind file:

```
public class A
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Test.Text = "blah";

        PropertyInfo p1 = this.GetType().GetProperty("Textbox");
        PropertyInfo p2 = new A().GetType().GetProperty("Prop");
    }
}
```

`p1` is `null` (`p2` isn't as expected). Why is it so? Is the `Window` type some kind of a special `object`? Or is it because the type of `Textbox` is generated as an `internal` field?

```
    #line 5 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
    internal System.Windows.Controls.TextBox Textbox;
```

Comment: `TextBox` isn't a property of `MainWindow`. It is an element added in the layout and that's it. Btw what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why you try get `"Textbox"` but in generated `Test;`?

Comment: @Grundy fixed the typo - edited code before adding to the post

Comment: so you use [Type.GetProperty Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx): _Searches for the **public property** with the specified name._ And public not same as internal

Comment: @Grundy Also bold the property too :) `Textbox` is a field not property.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel done! i missed that generated seems field instead property :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out yourself, `Textbox` is a field, not a property. In addition, it is not public, so you should try the following:

```
FieldInfo f1 = this.GetType().GetField("Textbox", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 5):

All named elements become internal fields, after XAML is compiled. This:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Textbox" Text=""/>
```

ultimately transforms to this:

```
internal TextBox TextBox;
```

Hence, to obtain metadata you have to call `GetField` this way:

```
GetType().GetField("NameInXaml", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```